# Setting environment variable for CHROME_BIN does not work

Tags: environment-variables, karma-runner

I'm trying to use Karma for testing my js scripts. In the doc it says I should set the environment variable for `CHROME_BIN`:

I've set it to

> %programfiles(x86)%"\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe

but when I type `%CHROME_BIN%` in DOS, it fails as it's truncated to `C:\Program` of the space in `Program Files`.

What can I do to work around with this problem?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Was facing the same issue and I solved it by editing the **karma.conf.js** and **karma-e2e.conf.js** files which is under **config** directory.

Change:

```
browsers = ['Chrome'];
```

**TO**

```
browsers = ['Your_System_Path_where_chrome_installed/chrome.exe'];
```

in my case it was > `C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe`

and then add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` path to  environment variables

---

**or in cmd**

```
SET CHROME_BIN = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

---

**Additional**: Settings for other browsers can be seen [here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/docs/config/03-browsers.md).

And about why chrome one is not working I guess they(Karma) have configured their chrome path from some earlier versions of chrome.

---

**Update:** For [AngularJS tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) Followers:

- You still might face problems (*as I faced*) while running karma test runner on some tutorial steps and to resolve this: just add these "Angular Scenario Dependencies" in both the "**...conf.js**" files, like this:

> ```
> files = [
>   ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
>   ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
>     ....
>     ....  // keep rest of the lines as it is
>     ....
> ];
> ```

Comment: this fixed my problem with `CHROME_BIN` not being set

Comment: following the angularJS tutorial, couldn't get it to work with env variables, nor with setting the path to chrome directly into karma conf files. What worked instead, is using default windows cmd and doing SET CHROME_BIN=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
I assume this edits the env variable but for some reason, it didn't work with default env variables in computer->advanced system settings.
Notice that my karma totally ignores what I setup in conf files, right now it is stated browsers = ['PhantomJS']; and it launches on chrome

Comment: setting CHROME_BIN environment also works with the note that you must open a new command prompt after the change

Comment: In case you need Chromium on Linux Mint then change browsers: ['Chrome'],  to browsers: ['Chromium'], in karma.conf.js

Answer (score 7):

In Powershell you can run the following command:

```
$Env:CHROME_BIN = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

You need to replace the stuff within the double quotes with your local path.

Or in cmd.exe

```
SET CHROME_BIN = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

This is all you would need to get it going.

Comment: I think that important thing to note is that, at least when working with cmd, it requires to restart cmd to work. Without restart after SET CHROME_BIN command it still doesn;t recognize this. After restart, everything is ok.

Comment: Thats @RobertJagoda **Restart** was very important! I wasted so much time trying to figure it out how it works. And then I saw your comment!

Answer (score 5):

I have solved the same issue by setting `CHROME_BIN` in my environment properties like this:

```
c:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
```

There have to be no double quotes (") around the property value and all backslash signs (\) have to be replaced by slash signs (/)

Answer (score 3):

For Chromium in ubuntu 14.04 edit test/karma.conf.js and change

```
browsers = ['Chrome'];
```

for

```
browsers = ['chromium-browser'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that installing Canary and changing `browsers = ['Chrome'];` to `browsers = ['ChromeCanary'];` is nicer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by running from an Administrator Command Prompt. No need to set CHROME_BIN and it will automatically point to your default installation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set` (see http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) and place the quotes around the entire string

"%programfiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe"

Comment: It's driving me nut. I've tried everything and I still can't get it to work. I even tried with powershell : [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("CHROME_BIN", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")  but no luck. Any idea what else I can try ?

Comment: @Sam sometimes those hiccups related to non admin mode, make sure you set the variable as _admin_

Comment: I'm definitely admin on my computer (I've tried both on my work computer and my personal computer, same problem)

Answer (score 0):

(In Linux) I thought it was related to CHROME_BIN but in the end for me it had nothing to do with that variable and i removed it.  I had to lookup the karma-chrome-launcher npm plugin on github and follow the instructions for adding no security to my karma config.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, some of us may have our chrome.exe file in the Program Files directory and not Program Files (x86), as a 64-bit application. So, the path may look like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```