# how to set "CHROME_BIN" env variable on cloud9 IDE when running react.js app

Tags: reactjs, npm, karma-runner, karma-mocha, cloud9

I set my [karma.conf.js](https://gist.github.com/ddeveloperr/33bbd4a02c0f960167b90a8ac07a08ff), installed [dependencies](https://gist.github.com/ddeveloperr/bcb4ba7aa63ce59ed70bd2ea7a642ed4) properly and after I "npm test" on my cloud9 IDE, react app 
I got the error:  'No binary for Chrome browser on your platform.
  Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable.'

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924263/how-to-fix-error-please-set-env-variable-chrome-bin-when-running-angular-js-wi) and all realted doesn't resolve my error?

Can anybody give me a hint please?

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app` ? Custom `webpack` configuration? or..?

Comment: I am using Custom webpack configuration.